# How to rename only some items in values() in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Like the title says I need to rename some items in a queryset. The code for the queryset is made like this:

```
data = SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.values('snpid__rsid', 'elementid__name', 'celllineid__name', 'countexperiments', 'filetype')
```

i tried to rename the values using `from django.db.models import F` but if I do

```
    data = SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.values(rsid=F('snpid__rsid'), FunctionalElement=F('elementid__name'), CellLine=F('celllineid__name'), 
        countexperiments=F('countexperiments'), filetype=F('filetype'))
```

it gives me an error because `countexperiments` and `filetype` are already the names assigned to the model to which they belong.
So is there a way to rename only a part of the values of the queryset mantaining the remaining ones?

Comment: Well i tried and it gives me this error : SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: sorry, the order does matter, my example is wrong: `values('countexperiments', rsid=F('sniped__rsid'))` will work. First the fields, then the `F` expressions.

Comment: @MattiaCarolo: you can not place named parameters before the positional ones.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks now works. Hope you can forgive a newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`.values(..)`** method [Djang-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) accepts both position parameters (strings of the names of the fields), and named parameters (expressions with alias names). For example:

```
SnpsFunctionalelement.objects.values(
    'countexperiments',
    'filetype',
    rsid=F('snpid__rsid'),
    FunctionalElement=F('elementid__name'),
    CellLine=F('celllineid__name')
)
```

Note that, as always in Python, the positional arguments should be placed *before* the named parameters (since otherwise the "position" is a rather *vague* concept).

Comment: Thanks a lot i am a newbie with python and I didn't knew this thing about positional parametrs